# Data set values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am receiving some data in data set.Can i compare the values in the table of a data set

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = db.ExecuteDataSet("select *  from tblSeatAssignmentDetails where SeatAssignmentID=" + SeatAssignmentId);
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count < ProcessID.Count())
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ProcessID.Count(); j++)
    {
        DBAccess db1 = new DBAccess();
        DataSet objds = new DataSet();
        objds = db1.ExecuteDataSet("Select * from tblSeatAssignmentDetails
                                        where ProcessID=" + ProcessID[j] + "");
        if (objds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        //here in this place i need to compare with the columns of the objds dataset column ie..processID)
        {
            string DeactivateDateTime = "null";
            i = db.ExecuteNonQuery("Insert INTO tblSeatAssignmentDetails Values(" + SeatAssignmentId + "," + ProcessID[j] + ",'" + DateTime.Now + "','1'," + DeactivateDateTime + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

//here in this place i need to compare with the columns of the objds dataset column ie..processID).

Is there any possibility of getting result.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: So there is a column named `processID` in `ds.Tables[0]` and `objds.Tables[0]`?

Comment: Always use parameterized queries, or sooner or later you will be a victim of the no. 1 cause of vulnerabilities in applications today: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve, or what the specific difficulty you're having is. Can you add more detail to your question?

Comment: Yes,there's a column with name processID....here what i am trying to do is objds.Tables[0].******==processID(//this processID is already saved first time on save button click and when i'm trying to update it,it is again repeating in the loop like when i save apple from listbox and on updation i add orange and grapes,along with orange and grapes the apple is also in the loop and getting updated.Now i am seeing apple,orange,grapes,apple.Here in my case apple should not be repeated.

Comment: I think you should do some research on DISTINCT queries.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
if (objds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    //here in this place i need to compare with the columns of the objds dataset column ie..processID)
    {
        string columnValueFromFirstResultSet = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["COLUMNNAME"].ToString();

        for (int i = 0; i < objds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            string columnValueOfFirstRow = objds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLUMNNAME"].ToString();

            if (columnValueFromFirstResultSet != columnValueOfFirstRow)
            {
                //Do something
            }
        }

        string DeactivateDateTime = "null";
        i = db.ExecuteNonQuery("Insert INTO tblSeatAssignmentDetails Values(" + SeatAssignmentId + "," + ProcessID[j] + ",'" + DateTime.Now + "','1'," + DeactivateDateTime + ")");
    }
```